# Using C++11 with Cocos2d-x for Android

Tags: c++11, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

The beginning of my issue is that I'm trying to use regular expressions in Cocos2d-x. For whatever reason, std::tr1::regex isn't working with C++98, so I'm trying to use std::regex with C++11 (along with some other C++11 features). This is working with iOS now, since it's really easy to change the version of C++ in Xcode, but I'm having all kinds of trouble getting this to work on Android.

I'm using the r8e version of the NDK with the gnustl_static library. I set the `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11` I've tried setting the toolchain version to clang (in addition to the default). Regardless of the toolchain, I am now able to compile my code, but it still crashes when I try to create a std::regex object `std::regex reg1("[a-z][0-3]*");` It seems like some people are able to get C++11 to work with the Android NDK expanded library (not the "minimal C++ runtime support library"), but I can't figure it out. I've read lots of ideas and I've tried most of them, and I've seen some clues, such as the following from CHANGES.html in the NDK docs:

```
    Patched GCC 4.4.3/4.6/4.7 libstdc++ to work with Clang in C++11
```

I don't know enough about how this all fits together, so could someone point me in the right direction? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you aren't restricted to using c++'s std::regex, you could try using standard C: regcomp() and regexec() .

Here a sample implementation (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html):

```
#include <regex.h>

int match(const char *string, const char *pattern)
{
    int    status;
    regex_t    re;


    if (regcomp(&re, pattern, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB) != 0) {
        return(0);      /* Report error. */
    }
    status = regexec(&re, string, (size_t) 0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&re);
    if (status != 0) {
        return(0);      /* Report error. */
    }
    return(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Open your Application.mk file and add following two lines at the end:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.7
```

**Note**: As you mentioned that you are using NDK's version r8e the toolchain version you need is 4.7. If it is r9, you can set it to 4.8.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! you saved me from this error. "'override' does not name a type"

Answer (score 0):

In Your android.mk add

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu++0x
```

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work either. As before, it compiled successfully, but crashed when it got to the regex section of code